# Yii2 module or controller routing

Tags: yii2, yii2-basic-app

I try use routing for module and controller

```
'<controller>'=>'<controller>/index',
                '<controller>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/view',
                '<controller>/<action>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
                '<module>' => '<module>/default/index',
                '<module>/<id:\d+>' => '<module>/default/view',
                '<module>/edit/<id:\d+>' => '<module>/default/edit',
                '<module>/delete/<id:\d+>' => '<module>/default/delete',
                '<module>/<action>' => '<module>/default/<action>',
                '<module>/<controller>' => '<module>/<controller>/index',
                '<module>/<controller>/edit/<id:\d+>' => '<module>/<controller>/edit',
                '<module>/<controller>/delete/<id:\d+>' => '<module>/<controller>/delete',
                '<module>/<controller>/<id:\d+>' => '<module>/<controller>/view',
                '<module>/<controller>/<action>' => '<module>/<controller>/<action>',
```

but for some reason, if the first matching rule did not work, then the rest are not checked, you get a 404 error.
For example, if the controller is not found, then 404 is obtained, and the check does not reach the modules.

url manager config

```
  'urlManager' => [
        'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
        'showScriptName' => false,
        'rules' => [
                'store/upload'=>'store/upload',
                'stores'=>'store/index',
            //    'post/<id:\d+>'=>'post/view',
                'comment/send'=>'comment/send',
                ['class' => 'yii\rest\UrlRule', 'controller' => 'Api',  'prefix' => 'api'],
                'api/<id:\d+>'=>'api/view',
                [
                        'pattern' => 'users',
                        'route' => 'users/index',
                        'suffix' => '/',
                        'normalizer' => false, // отключаем нормализатор для этого правила
                ],
           //     '<controller>'=>'<controller>/index',
   //             '<controller>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/view',
    //            '<controller>/<action>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
                '<module>' => '<module>/default/index',
                '<module>/<id:\d+>' => '<module>/default/view',
                '<module>/edit/<id:\d+>' => '<module>/default/edit',
                '<module>/delete/<id:\d+>' => '<module>/default/delete',
                '<module>/<action>' => '<module>/default/<action>',
                '<module>/<controller>' => '<module>/<controller>/index',
                '<module>/<controller>/edit/<id:\d+>' => '<module>/<controller>/edit',
                '<module>/<controller>/delete/<id:\d+>' => '<module>/<controller>/delete',
                '<module>/<controller>/<id:\d+>' => '<module>/<controller>/view',
                '<module>/<controller>/<action>' => '<module>/<controller>/<action>',


        ],
    ],
```

Request Url http://yii2/post
To PostController/actionIndex()

Comment: What is the requested URI? Show your UrlManager config.

Comment: I edit  qwestion

Comment: So if I see correctly (assuming what you have commented out is really commented out) this should hit `'<module>' => '<module>/default/index',`, right?

Comment: Yes.  If I uncomment what is commented out, how can I make it so that if it does not find the route '<controller>' => '<controller> / index', then continue checking with the module?

Answer (score 0):

I fix routing, It work.The controllers are checked first, then the modules.

```
 '<controller:\w+>'=>'<controller>/index',
                '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/view',
                '<controller:\w+>/<action>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
                '<module:\w+>' => '<module>/default/index',
                '<module:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<module>/default/view',
                '<module:\w+>/edit/<id:\d+>' => '<module>/default/edit',
                '<module:\w+>/delete/<id:\d+>' => '<module>/default/delete',
                '<module:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => '<module>/default/<action>',
                '<module:\w+>/<controller:\w+>' => '<module>/<controller>/index',
                '<module:\w+>/<controller:\w+>/edit/<id:\d+>' => '<module>/<controller>/edit',
                '<module:\w+>/<controller:\w+>/delete/<id:\d+>' => '<module>/<controller>/delete',
                '<module:\w+>/<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<module>/<controller>/view',
                '<module:\w+>/<controller:\w+>/<action>' => '<module>/<controller>/<action>',
```

Comment: Is this really working for routes like `/moduleName`, `/moduleName/id` or `/moduleName/actionName`?